# Why does my phone battery die at 0% then it has more battery when I turn it on again?

Tags: battery, 7.0-nougat, malware, virus

So after dying at 0% when I turn it on again, it can have more battery like 26%. Why does this happen?
Does this mean my phone has a virus?

Comment: a battery is not a glass of water where you can measure the exact filling level. percentage is only calculated from voltage (fluctuation = unsteadiness). it does only mean your battery is weak and should be replaced soon